# Why is this expression the Lagrangian dual problem of this QCQP?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

$\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}$
$\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbf{C}}$
$\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}$
$\newcommand{\bl}{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}$
$\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbf{b}}$
$\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbf{Q}}$
Reading this [great paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.09067.pdf#page=5&zoom=100,378,112), I am having difficulties understanding the following result:

> Let us consider a QCQP in a general form as
> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \min_{\bx\in\mathbb{R}^n}&\quad
> \bx^\top\bC_0\bx \tag{14}\label{14}\\
> \mathrm{s.t.}& \quad
> \bx^\top \bA_i\bx = b_i~,\quad i=1~,~\cdots~,m~.
> \end{align}
> $$
> [...]
> Its dual problem is
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \max_{\bl}&\quad\bb^\top\bl\tag{19}\label{19}\\
> \mathrm{s.t.}& \quad
> \bQ(\bl) = \bC_0 - \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i\bA_i \succeq 0.
> \end{align}
> $$
> where $\bb = [b_1,~\cdots~,~b_m],~\bl = [\lambda_1,~\cdots,~\lambda_m]\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
> Problem \ref{19} is called the Lagrangian dual problem of problem \ref{14}, and $\bQ(\bl)$ is the Hessian of the Lagrangian.

I understand that the Hessian of the Lagrangian $L(\bx,\bl):=\bx^\top\bC_0\bx - \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i(\bx^\top\bA_i\bx-b_i)$ w.r.t. the unknowns $\bx$ is given by (ignoring a multiplication by $2$): $\bQ(\bl)=\bC_0 - \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i\bA_i$.

However, I don't understand why \ref{14} can be generally reformulated by maximizing (w.r.t. the Lagrange multipliers $\bl$) the weighted sum of the values corresponding to the equality constraints: $\bb^\top\bl$ subject to $\bQ(\bl)$ being PSD.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The dual function $g(\lambda)=\min_{x} L(x,\lambda) = \min_{x} ( x^TQ(\lambda)x+\lambda^T b) = \lambda^T b$ since $Q(\lambda)$ is PSD.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thank you for your help. Why is it safe to assume $x$ will belong to the null space of $Q(\lambda)$ (i.e. that there are feasible points in the null space of $Q(\lambda)$)?

Comment: Pablo Parrilo, Sanjay Lall, [Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Programming](http://www.mit.edu/%7Eparrilo/cdc03_workshop/03_qcqp_2003_12_07_01_screen.pdf), 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I can write a step by step explanation to clarify what I think are your confusions. Let $p^*$ denote the optimal value of the original problem and $F$ its feasible set. We start with that  problem and write the Lagrangian

$$L(x,\lambda)=x^TC_0x-\sum_i\left(\lambda_ix^TA_ix-\lambda_ib_i\right)=x^TQ(\lambda)x+\lambda^Tb.$$

As always, by construction, $L$ has the property that whenever $x\in F$ is a feasible point and $\lambda$ is arbitrary then $L(x,\lambda)\leq x^TC_0x.$ Next, we proceed to compute the dual function

$$g(\lambda)=\min_x L(x,\lambda).$$

Note that the minimum is over all $x$, whether $x\in F$ or not is irrelevant here. Every value of $g(\lambda)$ will be a lower bound on $p^*$:

$$g(\lambda)=\min_x L(x,\lambda)\leq \min_{x\in F} L(x,\lambda) \leq \min_{x\in F} x^TC_0x=p^*$$

by what we already established. Therefore, to get the best lower bound on $p^*$ we want to make $g(\lambda)$ as large as possible, ie. maximize it, and then still:

$$\max_\lambda g(\lambda)\leq p^*.$$

Now what is $g(\lambda)$?

If $Q(\lambda)$ is not PSD, ie. has negative eigenvalue, then the expression $x^TQ(\lambda)x+\lambda^Tb$ can go to $-\infty$ by choosing $x$ to move along the eigenvector of that negative eigenvalue. If $Q(\lambda)\succeq 0$ then the minimizer in definition of $g(\lambda)$ will be $x=0$ and $g(\lambda)=\lambda^Tb$. Explicitly

$$
g(\lambda) = \begin{cases}\lambda^Tb & \mathrm{if}\ Q(\lambda)\succeq 0\\-\infty & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
So $$\max_\lambda g(\lambda)=\max_{\{\lambda:Q(\lambda)\succeq 0\}} g(\lambda)=\max_{\{\lambda:Q(\lambda)\succeq 0\}} \lambda^Tb$$ or in other words maximizing $g(\lambda)$ is the same as solving the problem

$$\mathrm{maximize}\ \lambda^Tb$$
$$\mathrm{s.t.}\ Q(\lambda)\succeq 0$$

which we call the dual and the optimum $d^*$ of that problem satisfies $d^*\leq p^*$.

### Comment

You are asking about the relation between primal and dual, if the objectives are equal, does $x$ have to be feasible etc. If you had a convex problem with strong duality then you would have $d^*=p^*$, but here you most likely only have $d^*\leq p^*$ and probably the inequality is strict in most cases because you are working with a nonconvex problem to start with. This procedure is only about deriving a lower bound.

Actually, it can also be explained in a different way because the paper you quote first relaxes (14) to a problem (18), which is a standard PSD rank relaxation, so the solution of (18) is obviously a lower bound on (14) (most likely not strict unless something extra can be proven). Then problems (18) and (19) are actually SDP duals (derivation of dual the same as here), so (18) and (19) have strong duality and the same objective value. That is summarized in the diagram you have on the same page of the paper.

The procedure I summarized is the same as shown for example in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/duality.html#lagrangian-and-the-dual-problem

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time. It has been really helpful :)
I think I understand it better now. 
Indeed, I was wrongly mixing the primal and the dual formulations.
One thing that surprises me, and that I don't grasp it yet fully, is that the constraint $Q(\lambda)\succeq0$ seems to constraint also $g(\lambda)=\min_xL(x,\lambda)$
since it affects the minimizer $x$ of $\min_xL(x,\lambda)$ (rather than just contraining $\max_\lambda g(\lambda)$). Does my confusion make any sense?

Comment: I don't know if that addresses your confusion but I added a completely explicit formula for $g$ and one extra line explaining the $max_\lambda g(\lambda)$ computation. I'm not sure I can do any better. Maybe you need to get used to it and/or dualize a few problems by hand to convince yourself. Of course in the whole derivation there is a counter-intuitive point where we suddenly forget that $x\in F$ and we let it be more general, but that's exactly because we want to get something new that will be independent of knowing the primal data - or we wouldn't be able to progress much.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed helps. I agree that I need to delve deeper as I am very new to duality. Thank you for all your help and time! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Because from

$$
\nabla_xL=C_0 x+\sum_i\lambda_i A_i x = 0
$$

pre multiplying by $x'$ we get

$$
x'C_0 x + \sum_i\lambda_i x'A_ix = x'C_0 x + \sum_i\lambda_i b_i=0
$$

then $x'C_0 x = -b'\lambda$ and $\min_x x'C_0x \equiv \max_{\lambda} b'\lambda$

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It has been really helpful. Just one more question: does this also imply that the constraint $Q(\lambda)\succeq0$ is necessary? I think I still don't grasp it fully.

Comment: In the cited paper $C_0$ is SPD.

Comment: Thanks again. Please let me know if I am wrong, but I feel that implying that $Q(\lambda)$ is PSD given that $C_0$ is PSD is not a sufficient condition since $Q(\lambda)$ also depends on the $-\lambda_iA_i$ terms (which I am not sure why they should satisfy any constraint).

Comment: If $Q(\lambda)$ is PSD then the intersection with $b'\lambda$ is compact, having as a result, maximum.

Comment: Thanks again. My apologies for asking multiple (and maybe trivial) questions. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate on your last point (perhaps adding it to the answer if you deem it to be best). I think I understand why the feasible set must be compact. However, I still don't understand why $Q(\lambda)$ must be PSD. For instance, I believe that imposing the constraint $Q(\lambda)\preceq0$ would also lead to a compact intersection.

Comment: $Q(\lambda)\succ 0$ is the condition for the dual function $g$ from my comment to be finite, otherwise you can choose $x$ that makes it go to $-\infty$.